# Label encode subgroups after groupby

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, group-by, label-encoding

I want to label encode subgroups in a pandas dataframe. Something like this:

```
| Category   | | Name      |
| ---------- | | --------- | 
| FRUITS     | | Apple     |
| FRUITS     | | Orange    |
| FRUITS     | | Apple     |
| Vegetables | | Onion     |
| Vegetables | | Garlic    |
| Vegetables | | Garlic    |
```

to

```
| Category   | | Name    | | Label |
| ---------- | | ------- | | ----- |
| FRUITS     | | Apple   | | 1     |
| FRUITS     | | Orange  | | 2     |
| FRUITS     | | Apple   | | 1     |
| Vegetables | | Onion   | | 1     |
| Vegetables | | Garlic  | | 2     |
| Vegetables | | Garlic  | | 2     |
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to group-by "Category" and then group-by "Name" and use `.ngroup()`:

```py
df["Label"] = (
    df.groupby("Category")
    .apply(lambda x: x.groupby("Name", sort=False).ngroup() + 1)
    .values
)
print(df)
```

Prints:

```
     Category    Name  Label
0      FRUITS   Apple      1
1      FRUITS  Orange      2
2      FRUITS   Apple      1
3  Vegetables   Onion      1
4  Vegetables  Garlic      2
5  Vegetables  Garlic      2
```

Comment: I tried this but got a size mismatch error:
ValueError: Length of values (21379) does not match length of index (21436)

Comment: @rohitderaj  Do you have `NaN`s in `Category` column? Try to clean your dataframe first of NaNs.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`factorize`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.factorize.html) per group:

```
df['Label'] = (df.groupby('Category')['Name']
               .transform(lambda x: pd.factorize(x)[0])
               .add(1)
               )
```

Output:

```
     Category    Name  Label
0      FRUITS   Apple      1
1      FRUITS  Orange      2
2      FRUITS   Apple      1
3  Vegetables   Onion      1
4  Vegetables  Garlic      2
5  Vegetables  Garlic      2
```